# Android - OnItemClickListener listview

Tags: android, menubar, onitemclicklistener

Here's what I want to do:

[image: List of Tasks BEFORE CLICK]

I have this list of tasks. When I click on one of the items I want this to appear:

[image: AFTER CLICKING ON A TASKS]

Assuming that menubar can be found with

```
findViewById(R.id.menubar);
```

Can someone please tell what code I have to put onItemClickListener

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { 
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
```

**NOTE:** The menubar visibility its set as GONE.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out the answer. Apparently, when you fill a view with lots of tasks, the adapter does not fill everything when you load the layout, so everytime you scroll down, hes putting more items on the listview.

What you have to do is make sure you put a field "loaded" and, in case is false, it does not show the menubar below that item, otherwise, when you click in one of the items of that list, when you scroll down, since they will have the same relative position (if you click on the first item, the position = 0, when you scroll down, there will be another position = 0) the menubar will appear on both items.

Hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at the code, a precise answer is not possible. However, when I first wanted to implement a "Quick Action Bar" similar to the one you have shown, I had followed this example here:

http://code.google.com/p/simple-quickactions/

And this with some styling put in: https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction3D

Hope this helps....

Comment: Thanks. Ive tried one of those examples. My problem is not exactly showing the quickaction bar, its puttin it in the right place. For example, if I press the item "FICHEIROS" the QuickActionBar will appear in "FOTOS" ...

Comment: it really is difficult where things are going wrong without seeing some relevant code. Post some of it and then a better solution can be offered.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit difficult without seeing any code, but I can give you some logic ideas.

Based on your description, I'm assuming that those quick bar controls are hidden on EACH listview item so, it goes:

Fotos (visible)

Action Controls (hidden)

[End of Item]

PROJECTOS (visible)

Action Controls (hidden)

...

I think the OnItemClick method gives you the view (item: Fotos, Projectos, etc) that was clicked as the 2nd argument. If you cast that back to whatever layout you used to create the listview items, you should be able to use findViewByID to get access to the hidden controls that are on each listview and make them visible.

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {           
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
    { 
         //Assuming each item is a linear layout
         LinearLayout itemAsLL = (LinearLayout)view;

         //find the action bar controls
         LinearLayout actionControlsLayout = itemAsLL.findViewById(R.name.of.actioncontrols.id);

         //Make it visible
         actionControlsLayout.setVisibility(VIEW.Visible);
     }
```

You would need to find a way to hide those controls when another item is clicked? Maybe save the view (or position in the adapterView ) as a class variable and when another item is clicked, go to that view/find that view and hide the controls.